# How to bind Grid ColumnDefinition.Width in the Universal Platform?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Sorry, I have not found the answer.

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Background="LightGray" >
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="30"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Column1 , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="30"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBox Text="0"/>
  </Grid>
  <Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBox Text="1"/>
  </Grid>
  <Grid Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBox Text="2"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
  private GridLength _column1 = new GridLength(10);
  public GridLength Column1
  {
    get
    {
      return _column1;
    }
    set
    {
     _column1 = value;
    }
  }

  public MainPage()
  {
    this.InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

What is wrong with this code? 
by the way, is there ability to left Grid.ColumnDefinitions section in xaml and set ColumnDefinition properties direct for column (do not set variable for every property in code behind)

Comment: you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` .

Comment: thanks for the answer, I implemented it and it does not help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, I see that the `Value` property of `GridLength` is readonly (no set method). You can define a `DependencyProperty` of type double, and register a `PropertyChangedCallback` to it to change the Width of that specific column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension) use the **DataContext** as a default source, if you want to bind the `Column1` property in your page behind code, you should specify this page's data context, so just add the following code in your MainPage's constructor.

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //Add this code to specify the binding's data context
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

---Update---

Generally, we use the Binding to bind a Data model's property, if you want to change the column/Grid value by changing some parameters from code behind, you can implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) interface and make the property subscribe the [PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) Event, Here is a simple code sample base on your above code,

In the xaml, I add a Button to change the `Column1` property in its click event,

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Background="LightGray" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column0" MaxWidth="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Column1 , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="30"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBox Text="0"/>
        <Button Content="click me to change the Column 1's width" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox Text="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBox Text="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code behind of implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) interface.

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage: Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private GridLength _column1 = new GridLength(20);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    public GridLength Column1
    {
        get
        {
            return _column1;
        }
        set
        {
            _column1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Column1");
        }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //Add this code to specify the binding's data context
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    Double width = 20;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Column1 = new GridLength(width += 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank Breeze Liu - MSFT a lot for the answer. It really cool feature to bind data (if I understand it right) but maybe  i wrote not clear enought, I would like to change column/Grid design  depend on some parameters from code behind. One again, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @user1820916 I have updated my answer, you can check it. If you are not familar with the Data binding and want to get more about it, I suggest you to look into the document [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart) and [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

Comment: Oh thank you a lot! you are fully right, I am brand new in it.